# change the format of the array returned from a sql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't even know if what I would like is possible but here you go:
I have a stored procedure returning an array with all the data I need but not in the format that I would like: I have

a table `USER`

a table `TYPE`

a table `USER_TYPE (foreign key user_id from USER, type_id from TYPE)`

a table `GAME`

a table `USER_GAME (foreign key user_id from USER, game_id from GAME)`

And I have a query with JOINS:

```
SELECT user_name,type_name,game_name

FROM user u

INNER JOIN user_type ut
    ON u.user_id=ut.user_id

INNER JOIN type t
      ON ut.type_id=t.type_id

LEFT JOIN user_game ug
    ON u.user_id=ug.user_id

INNER JOIN game g
    ON ug.game_id=g.game_id

WHERE t.type_name = ?

...
```

So I get an array in the following format:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [type] => type1
        [game] => game1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [type] => type1
        [game] => game2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [type] => type2
        [game] => game2
    )
```

etc...

but I would like the query to return an array such as

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [type] => type1
        [game1] => game1
        [game2] => game2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [type] => type2
        [game1] => game1
        [game2] => game2
    )
```

etc...

Thus listing all the games for one user in each array: I guess I would need to basically keep the join on type, get the various user_id from it and then get the games for each of those various user_id, and kind of merge all that.
That would be great if that could be done inside the procedure itself.

I hope that wasn't unreadable, would be very grateful for any help.
By the way if any of you could direct me towards good tutorials about more advanced sql queries 'cause I'm a bit short on that...
Thank you very much!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Are you really returning an **array** from your stored procedure? Why not return a regular resultset?

Comment: Are you sure that user always will have only two games for each type?

Comment: Hi guys, i'm using mysql and the number of games can actually vary, and that would be easier to keep the output as an array.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a PHP side structure, not MySQL. Your stored procedure will return a resultset and you will have to loop through the PHP array to fetch all games from each gamer.